# What is in the code for RuntimeException that makes it unchecked?

Tags: java, exception

I understand that checked exceptions inherit from `Exception` and that unchecked exceptions extend `RuntimeException`. But looking at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.java.html), I can't see what's in RuntimeException that makes it unchecked.

In fact, if I make my own class called `MyRuntimeException` and literally copy-paste the code from `RuntimeException` (after stripping out the package declaration and changing the class name), the resulting class will be checked. That is, when I try to throw a MyRuntimeException, the compiler will complain that the exception needs to be caught or declared to be thrown. However, throwing a `RuntimeException` compiles without error.

What magic pixie dust is in the built-in RuntimeException that makes it unchecked?

Edit: Is it possible for me, as an end-user programmer, to build my own Exception hierarchy and replicate the behavior of checked and unchecked exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pixie dust is not in the `RuntimeException` class. It is in the compiler that treats `RuntimeException` and its derived classes differently from other exceptions.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is better than the top answer in the duplicate question.